# Provide parameters to OpenCV C++ program in ROS from external file

Tags: c++, file, opencv, parameters, ros

I want to write a program using **OpenCV C++** interface in **ROS**. I want to provide parameters used by the program from external file(not sure which format will be apt).

Say, I use the threshold function in the program, **instead of changing the threshold value each time in the program,make and then run**, 
I want the program to fetch the threshold value from a file so that **if I wish to change any value, I could do it in the external file**.

I want this because I think **it will be helpful to a third-person who can just change the various parameters in the file and observe the result** rather than opening the program, change values,make and run (*Sometimes the third person may not be a programmer and just wishes to see the results, in that case he would not know the technicalities of where to change parameters in the program*)

Is there any way to do this in **ROS** ?? Any method for just a **C++** program requiring  several parameters could also be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

well, if it's just simple params:

```
#include <fstream>

// write:
int param1 = 17;
float param2=2.5f;
ofstream o("params.txt");
o << param1 << endl;
o << param2 << endl;

// read:
int param1;
float param2;
ifstream i("params.txt");
i >> param1;
i >> param2;
```

similar idea, bit more advanced, for opencv stuff, use the FileStorage, it's a key-value store:

```
Mat face_labels;
Mat face_features;

cv::FileStorage fs("face.yml",cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "L" << face_labels;
fs << "F" << face_features;

cv::FileStorage sf("face.yml",cv::FileStorage::READ);
sf["L"] >> face_labels;
sf["F"] >> face_features;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via ROS parameters. See the [roscpp params tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters) and the more detailed [roscpp params overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server). You probably want to go ahead and use the NodeHandle::param(...) form as it makes it easy to specify defaults.